# How many $6$-digit numbers can be formed using $\{1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$ with each digit appearing twice read the same from left to right as right to left

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem here.

> How many $6$-digit numbers can be formed using $\{1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$ with each digit appearing twice which read the same when read from left to right and from right to left? For example, $42124, 212$.

Because they have a maximum of 2 repetitions, the first three digits must be distinct, otherwise it is repeated 4 or 6 times.
So in this case, the first or last three digits must be 
9⋅8⋅7 
But the other three digits must be a repetition of the other three digits (because we want it to be the same number from the left or right)
7⋅8⋅9 
And on the other hand, we want the first and last digits, the fifth and second digits, and the fourth and third digits to be the same.
So if I get in general, we can say that:
9⋅8⋅7⋅7⋅8⋅9 
And my question is what is the guarantee that the first and last digits are the same?
I'm very sorry for the question, but I'm very confused

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The main thing is that what I explained was true or not?

Comment: Please clarify the statement of the original question by separating it from your thoughts about the question so that we can evaluate whether you are thinking about the actual question correctly.

Comment: Are you asking for six digit numbers that repeat each digit twice, and read the same from left to right, and right to left ?

Comment: Yes, I mean that, but each number should be repeated at most twice

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Is that clear now?

Comment: I have edited your question.  Please confirm that what I have written is what you intended.

Comment: yep it is ,thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the number reading the same from left to right, and right to left, the configurations can only be of the type

$ABCCBA$ which also conforms to the "at most two repetitions" stipulation.

You can form $9*8*7 =504$ such numbers using digits $1\;thru\;9$
such as $124421, \;387783$ etc

Numbers or words that read the same from left to right and right to left are known as **palindromes**

Comment: Thank you, I got my answer

Comment: You're welcome !